# What's the "active state" for a Bootstrap data-toggle called?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to emulate a feature on Wikipedia's mobile pages. If you visit http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mammal and scroll down to the heading "Distinguishing Features," then click it, you'll see the down arrow (chevron) change to an up arrow.

I inserted the two choices into my header via spans...

```
<h2 id="where" class="H2Toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data- target=".Header2,.Where,#glyph2">
 <span class="glyphicon glyphicon1 glyphicon-chevron-down"></span>
 <span id="glyph2" class="glyphicon glyphicon2 glyphicon-remove-sign"></span>
</h2>
```

I then added a CSS style - span#glyph2 { display: none; }

Now only the first span displays by default, but when I click on the header BOTH spans display. So I need to figure out how to make the first span not display when I click the header, then reappear when I click it again.

I could do it for a particular screen size. For example, I could make one span or the other appear or not appear if the screen is 1,000 pixels wide or wider. But I need a CSS style (or JavaScript function) that makes a character appear/disappear according to whether or not a header has been clicked.

So I guess what I'm asking is "What's the name of the default active vs the inactive state in Bootstrap?"

Comment: on the link you gave it just collapses that section not changes the content? but if im understanding you right you will need to use something like the jquery toggle to switch between

Comment: My article is divided into sections. Clicking a header alternately opens and closes sections. But at the same time, I want to display a down-arrow (when the section is closed) and an up arrow (or X) when the section is open. I thought I might need to create some sort of toggle switch, but I don't know how to do it.

Comment: `data-toggle` is not something jQuery provides; I had to dig through some documentation to find that you’re *actually* using a Bootstrap feature. I’m editing this into your question, but you probably should know this in case you have future problems.

Comment: i used words rather than arrows but is this what you mean? http://jsfiddle.net/vcwoLpox/ update with the button removed but with the click event being the words which you could replace with arrows http://jsfiddle.net/vcwoLpox/1/

Comment: Parody - Yes, that's it. I can probably modify your JSFiddle script to work with mine, so you just gave me the correct answer. ;)

Comment: @ icktoofay - Thanks. Yes, I just started playing with Bootstrap and am still learning the ropes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bootstrap will apply the `collapsed` class to the trigger when the element it controls is collapsed. Otherwise, no such class is applied. You can use this to write an appropriate CSS rule.

```css
.only-collapsed { display: none; }
.collapsed .only-collapsed { display: inline; }
.collapsed .only-expanded { display: none; }
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#target">Header <span class="only-collapsed">Expand</span> <span class="only-expanded">Collapse</span></div>
<div id="target" class="collapse in">Hello, world!</div>
```

Comment: I marked that as the correct answer, as it's working - with one minor snag. When I refresh my page, the header displays X, rather than the down arrow. When I click on the header, the content opens and X displays (as it should). When I click the header a second time, the content closes, and the down arrow displays (as it should). But when I refresh the page, it displays X, instead of the down arrow. I'll post my code next...

Comment: This is how I modified your code:

    <h2 id="where" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#where2">
     <span class="only-collapsed glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-down"></span>
     <span id="glyph2" class="only-expanded glyphicon glyphicon-remove-sign"></span>
     Where am I?
    </h2>
    <section id="where2" class="collapse ConSec">